# How would you Clamp the relative position of an object?(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clamp, magnitude, vector2

How would I clamp the magnitude of a relative position and convert to world coordinates? i.e. *`(this.pos - other.pos).clampMag(3f).toWorldCoor();`* of course this doesn't exist, but how would I do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with [Vector3.ClampMagnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html) and [Transform.TransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html)? If not I believe you could simply use:

```
Vector3 localClamped = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(yourLocalVector, maxLength);
Vector3 worldPos = someTransform.TransformPoint(localClamped);
```

If you don't have a local transform you are working with, you can take your `localClamped` `Vector3` and add whatever offset `Vector3` you are working with.

```
Vector3 worldPos = localClamped + offset;
```

Comment: thanks! I could use this for gameobjs?

Comment: i was thinking of locking an obj in a certain rad of another;

Comment: Yes, you definitely can through a GameObject's transform property, i.e. gameObject.transform